# Software for Binary Integer Linear Programs

Tags: soft-question, optimization, math-software, integer-programming, operations-research

I am aware that there is good software out there to solve integer linear programs (ILPs). However, is there (preferably free or low cost) software I could use to solve large binary integer linear programs (BILPs) for commercial applications efficiently? I know that BILPs are special cases of ILPs and thus can be solved using the same algorithms, but I think that BILPs have special algorithms too that are more efficient than ILP algorithms. Preferably I would like to be able to use the software in Java/C/C++ or be able to call the software from these languages.

Comment: Take a look at the solvers at [COIN-OR](http://www.coin-or.org/projects/). There are several open-source discrete linear solvers that you can choose from.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you really mean when you mention "for commercial applications".

I recently used [GLPK](http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) through some python bindings which mimic its C library API. I used it on a BILP that had 11K variables and 20K constraints. GLPK is licensed under the GLPv3.

Many years ago, as a student, I did a similar project with [lp_solve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/), which also has a C API. It is LGPL.

Both solvers also exist as command line utilities which can process problems in documented text formats.